Побитовый сдвиг и byte order
Допустим есть две машины одна с little-endian, другая с big-endian, на них выполняется побитовый сдвиг числа.
unsigned int a = 0x80000000;
unsigned int b = a >> (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT) - 1; // <-- Будет ли результат одинаковый на обеих машинах? (1)


Будет ли результат одинаков на обеих машинах?

Примечание. Относительно недавно я задавал похожий вопрос (про битовые операции в целом и там ответ оказался достаточно прост и очевиден, что логично), но я не уверен, что тот ответ распространяется на побитовый сдвиг.

Да, на обеих в результате будет b = 1

Да. Откуда таки мысли вообще? Различаться будет только результат операций с извлечением отдельных байтов.

@MBo ну вообще один из ответов на прошлый вопрос был примерно такой: little-endian: 01 00 00 00 & 01 00 00 00 == 01 00 00 00. Big-endian: 00 00 00 01 & 00 00 00 01 == 00 00 00 01, вот оттуда собственно и такие мысли, но спасибо за ответ.

А вот в памяти 0x80000000 и 0x00000001 на little и big-endian машинах будут лежать по разному. В little 0: 00, 1: 00, 2: 00, 3: 80 и 0:01 1: 00, 2: 00, 3: 00; а в big 0: 80, 1: 00, 2: 00, 3: 00 и 0: 00 1: 00, 2: 00, 3: 01

был примерно такой - и что? В обоих случаях это одно и тоже число.

@MBo я понимаю, что это одно и то же число, вы просто спросили откуда такие мысли, и я вам показал ответ являющийся причиной этих мыслей (не вижу смысла расписывать здесь мой ход мыслей насчет битового сдвига). В любом случае, спасибо за ответ.

@avp Благодарю за ответ.

Да, результат не зависит от endianness. (В смысле число будет то же, а представление в памяти конечно другое.)
<< и >> в стандерте определены через арифметические операции - умножить/поделить на степень двойки, и т.д.
http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.shift
